# Failed to Create AppDomain

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

What is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcWDB.jpg) Error For?
I repaired my Vs but this did not solve it.
[image]

My OS :  Windows 7 64 bit home edition.
Visual studio 2010 Ultimate.
Does My question need more information?

Comment: You have not provided enough information. Is the website running under cassini? IIS? What version of the OS? Is ASP.NET properly installer and registered? Anything in the log files?

Comment: i was uploaded image of error but there is no image!

Comment: @Oded : Because image is Clear. thanks.

Comment: This can be if asp.net registration is corrupt.
Try to run: aspnet_regiis -i in the visual studio command prompt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite late but still hope this will be useful for somebody:

I got into the same nightmare these days and none of the found solutions worked for me. I tried this link [codeproject.com](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/113246/Failed-to-Create-AppDomain-in-Visual-Studio-2010.aspx) and the `Capsol` command was not found by the VS Command Line, and renaming the files didn't work either.

So, today I decided to simply delete (backup first!) the folder `v2.0.50727` located into `#:\Documents and Settings\{user}\Application Data\Microsoft\CLR Security Config` and Voila! VS is debugging again.

Answer (score 8):

The answer that worked for me was change the 'web.config' file
from

```
<trust legacyCasModel="true" />
```

to

```
<trust legacyCasModel="false" />
```

Comment: <trust> element requires attribute `level`, i.e. `<trust level="full" legacyCasModel="false" />`

Answer (score 2):

If for some reason you were tweaking your CAS settings, this might have caused it:

http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2005/03/16/5345.aspx

Get a fresh copy of the security config file and see if that fixes it:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/364087/event-id-1088-error-code-0x80131501

or,

Visual Studio Command Prompt -> caspol -reset

Comment: There Is No Download link here : https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/364087/event-id-1088-error-code-0x80131501      where can i get fresh copy of config settings?

Comment: Do a Repair install of VS 2010 or search your install software for it.

Comment: i said i did repair but problem exist yet.

Comment: i did runt this command -> Visual Studio Command Prompt -> caspol -reset but problem is exist yet.

Comment: You need to locate Security.Config and replace it with an older version.

Comment: Re-build your machine... I honestly can't think of anything else. Also, if your VS install is on a physical CD, make sure it's not corrupted.

Comment: Hi, shaahin have you solved this issue.. I have the same issue